# What is the purpose of the fourth argument in a Zend Framework Route instantiation?

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-route

Here is an example of a Route, taken from [this page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html):

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
    'blog/archive/(\d+)-(.+)\.html',
    array(
        'controller' => 'blog',
        'action'     => 'view'
    ),
    array(
        1 => 'id',
        2 => 'description'
    ),
    'blog/archive/%d-%s.html'
);
$router->addRoute('blogArchive', $route);
```

I can see that it matches paths that follow the pattern `'blog/archive/(\d+)-(.+)\.html'`, redirecting to the `blog` controller and `view` action, and passing along the `id` and `description` parameter. But, what is the purpose of the fourth argument; `'blog/archive/%d-%s.html'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the question and found the answer on the page a few seconds later; what a surprise.

> Since regex patterns are not easily
>   reversed, you will need to prepare a
>   reverse URL if you wish to use a URL
>   helper or even an assemble method of
>   this class. This reversed path is
>   represented by a string parsable by
>   sprintf() and is defined as a fourth
>   construct parameter.